# VueJS local not found in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vue-cli-3

When browsing to `http://localhost:8080/` in chrome I get redirected to a bad request page, provided by the chrome browser. If I browse to the network url **ie:** `http://192.168.1.1:8080/`, then the chrome browser happily loads it.

The localhost url works fine in Firefox and in Edge.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Check your chrome proxy settings and hosts file, also try the guest and private mode, it might be a cookies problem

Comment: Thank you @CaddyDZ it was a cookie issue. I suspect something to do with the OidcClient, and that I am trying to run the app from the office rather than from home but the cookies syncing in chrome via my google account. Please add your comment as an answer to the question so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your chrome proxy settings and hosts file, also try the guest and private mode.

It might be a cookies problem